# Programming against WSDL without access to actual webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I'm going to use C# to read data from a few webservices. I've done that many times before, but those times I've had direct access to the webservices from my development machine.

In this project I've just been sent a .wsdl file, and a couple of .xsd files for the webservice they have in their local intranet.

I've seen that I can use "Add Web Reference", and point directly to the .wsdl file, so that a C# class is created.

But how can I really test it? I'd like to return some dummy data that I can visualize while I develop. Any tips for this situation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Mock Webservice](http://iandykes.blogspot.com/2008/06/creating-mock-web-services-in-net.html)

From the above source, a .cs file can be generated by opening a Visual Studio Command Prompt and running something like the following:

> wsdl /language:CS /namespace:Your.Namespace.Here
>   /out:Directory\To\Save\To\ /protocol:SOAP /serverinterface
>   finally-your-wsdl-file-here.wsdl

Comment: Its perfactly ok to ask here without googling. This thread should be the first hit when someone google!

Comment: No objection to that. This was no critique, just an info where the link came from.

Comment: what type of sample data does this mock web service return?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try SOAP UI for mocking up service with ease. (Free web service testing tool)

Check:

http://www.soapui.org/gettingstarted/mocking.html

Answer (score 1):

The [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) tool bundled with the Windows SDK (found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin) is a nice command line tool that generates WCF client proxies.  I've found this to be a good way to interrogate a WSDL.  It'll create an interface for the service and then a proxy class that implements that interface.  You can then mock up something else that implements that interface to facilitate testing.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to create your own server side stub. Assuming you want to do it with WCF, then [go here](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx). You can then add some basic logic to get your client working.

You can also use the legacy Web Service functionality via the [WSDL tool's /Server option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx), though I recommend you use WCF.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try a product like "Fiddler" (http://www.fiddler2.com)

It allows you to capture HTTP (or HTTPS) packets and send a fake automated reply file back as if the server had sent the response. I use it for my project and it works wonders when the test server goes offline (which is often). I take an old response packet, save it as a text file, then send it back again and the application I'm building has no idea it didn't come from the actual host.

Answer (score 0):

I've also found this article very useful: https://ivangrigoryev.com/en/how-to-mock-a-web-service-in-dot-net/
It describes the steps needed, from downloading the WSDL file and to the creation of the test project:

1. Get WSDL somehow
2. In the VS Command Prompt:

   wsdl /language:CS /out:C:\Downloads\ /protocol:SOAP /serverinterface C:\Downloads\webservice.wsdl
3. Create a new ASP .NET Web Application with an empty template
4. Add the file, generated on step 2, to the project
5. Add a new service to the project (Add -> New item -> Web Service (ASMX))
6. Change the class definition in the code for this added web service, so it implements the right interface, e.g replace System.Web.Services.WebService with yours.
7. Hit Alt+Enter and implement the interface automatically with stubs.
8. Hit F5, the service will run and your browser will open, copy the URL and use it instead of the real URL.

**This works only in .Net Framework** since .Net Core and .Net 5 dropped the WCF server support. But I found it acceptable to have the main project on .Net 5, but this mock service on .Net Fw 4.8